# Change a font style in a TextBox

Tags: c#

I have several text box's where input is added.  All these input are then displayed in a text box at the bottom of the program after the button is clicked.

I want to make the just one of those strings to display as italics in the text box at the bottom of the program.

Here is what I have.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string author;
            string name;
            string year;
            string title;
            string place;
            string publisher;

```
        name = textBox2.Text + ", ";
        author = textBox1.Text + ". ";
        year =  "(" + textBox3.Text + ") ";
        title = textBox4.Text + ", ";
        place = textBox5.Text + ", ";
        publisher = textBox6.Text + ".";


        // output to reference field


        richTextBox1.Text = name + author + year + title + place + publisher;

    }
```

What i want is to display the title string in italics.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.Find(title, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
```

That should italicize the title of the book and only the title of the book, while keeping the font the same as the rest of the rich text box.